# Simulate ctrl+v event on javascript

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, keyevent

I try to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in javascript. I use firefox in Linux. What I do is:

```
var pressEvent = document.createEvent ("KeyboardEvent");    
pressEvent.initKeyEvent ("keypress", true, true, window, true, false, false, false, 86, 0);
var accepted=aTarget.dispatchEvent (pressEvent);
```

Somebody knows why it doesn't work??

Thanks

Comment: Security reasons? You can't just read the clipboard without the user letting you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: @JanDvorak how can the user let you do this?

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee you could provide the user a textbox to paste into. Opacity:0 might work, but the CTRL+V does have to be there.

Comment: @JanDvorak Is there something like `Notification.requestPermission()` for that?

Comment: Not that I know of. Plus, if a website asked me, "hey, may I monitor your clipboard while I'm open", I'd run like hell and never come back.

Answer (score 6):

Copy and Paste and the clipoard itself are very protected. Unless there is explicit user action it won't work with simulations. If you make a script that simulates a paste inside a inputbox then submit that to your server, you might get some really private info from people clipboards. So...no, that won't work to my knowledge. I would love for you or someone else to prove me wrong and share the solution.

But do tell what you're planning to do and maybe there's a workaround it that doesn't involve this simulated action.

Comment: I don't think it'll be a security problem, because it works in Windows.. What I want to do is cut some text and paste it in other place. Simulate ctrl+a and ctrl+x works fine but ctrl+v not.

Comment: @TheBrain I'm attempting to create a clipboard context menu option. When a user clicks one of the submenus, it pastes the associated text into whatever textbox/page is active.